# Tips needed! Program has wrong behavior using inline asm to call function instead of C function

Tags: optimization, inline-assembly, osdev, context-switch, fpu

I'm currently writing my own operating system. It is a non-preemptive OS and my threads are working fine with the scheduler. I have one edge case though. If I don't call my `yield()` function from C but do `asm("call yield")` the calculations later on fails but only with `-O2` optimization.

> Like many have said, it is always our fault

I have tried all approaches i can think of but now I'm desperate.

So if anybody has some tips on what might be happening or what i should investigate please share.

I guess this gets shutdown for being offtopic but any tips is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you do `yield()`? Are there other blocks of inline assembly before and after `asm("call yield")` ? Generally speaking it is easiest to create a `switchtask()`function written as pure assembly in an assembly module to do task switching. Trying to do it in _C_ is difficult (not impossible) but you need to know what you are doing and inline assembly is one of those things that is difficult to get right. If you are going for robustness and you are new to the intricacies of inline assembly - I say [Don't use Inline asm](https://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/DontUseInlineAsm)

Comment: The only reason for doing this call is to check the robustness of the context switch. There are no other good reasons for calling yield in this fashion.

Comment: Doing `asm("call yield")` introduces a new set of issues and by itself will not be a test of robustness when in fact it adds a new layer of problems.Do you have reason to believe that yield is failing in some way when doing it directly in _C_ (via `yield()`) ?

Comment: Yes. Tanks for the comments. I finally has a suspicion. I have one line of C in the yield function before calling my real scheduler handler written in assembler. I think that line with -O2 optimization removes the safeties expected from the call. I shall rewrite that line with inline asm an see if that fixes the problem :-)

Comment: Well my previous suspicion of the yield call function did not pan out. But now i think I finally have the right culprit. After close examination of the disassembly it seems that the normal code got help from the compiler in storing the state of the FPU. In the -O2 optimization the compiler does not store the state of the FPU before my call. I will try to figure out how to handle the FPU state. Which in retrospect my context switch system should handle. My test has obviously not been thorough enough.

Comment: To all new readers: please read my conclusion about the FPU state.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the compiler generates a call to a function, it preserves the contents of any registers which may be modified by the called function ("caller-save registers") before making the call.

Since you've buried this function call within an inline assembler block, the compiler doesn't know it needs to save and restore registers around the call.

Simple solution: Don't do that, then. If you want to call a function, use C function call syntax.

Complicated solution: Declare which registers this function call will clobber using [extended inline assembler syntax](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I completely agree. This is kinda a test for the robustness of my implementation. But i also fails when doing a `asm("pushal; call yield; popal;")` although as you sad that might still be the same issue. And like stated above it only happens with -O2. Do you have any other remarks to this?

Comment: Yes, but i can not see any obvious problems with the generated code. I have been looking at it for so long now that I have probably gone code-blind.

Comment: I have marked you answer as the solution but I'm still interested in tips in how on how i might get this working.

Comment: @EspenNilsen What does `asm("pushal; call yield; popal;" ::: "memory")` give you?

Comment: I made a small typo in the first version of the last post.I had 2 colons originally instead of  3

Comment: @MichaelPetch Sadly the same result. But after comments from all of you i now think i can solve the problem by trying to remove the one line of C code i have in the yield function. (I set the PCB (Process control block) to a new state).  I think i could mange to do this form a function i can create in assembler and perhaps the -O2 will not destroy my code.

Comment: Still the correct answer to my question, I believe is what duskwuff wrote; Don't do it :-)

Comment: To all new readers: please read my conclusion about the FPU state.

Comment: @EspenNilsen and duskwuff: even with clobbers on all the registers, it's still not necessarily safe, depending on the ABI.  x86-64 System V has a red zone below RSP that's safe from async clobber, but GNU C inline asm syntax has no way to tell the compiler you want to clobber it.  So you'd need to `add $-128, %rsp` before you push anything on the stack, to avoid stepping on the compiler's red-zone.  Usually you should just write a whole function in asm if you need this level of hackery.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks for all the comments. It helped allot. I finally figured it out. My context switch did not handle the state of the FPU. After going back to dissable once again I observed that the normal generated C code helped me save the FPU state.

After implementing FSAVE/FNSAVE and FRSTOR in the context switch the -O2 optimized code also worked as expected.

@melpomene: As you asked:

> Have you looked at the generated code?

In retrospect, obviously not hard enough.

Thanks for all suggestions, and I hope this thread can help others to remember the x87 FPU instructions now :-P